# Log4J com múltiplas JVMs

Tags: java, jvm, log4j

## Contexto

No projeto que estou (ambiente produção) tem um servidor que está instalado com 4 aplicações java, sendo:

- 1 aplicação deployada Jetty
- 1 aplicação em Tomcat
- 2 jar gerado com framework Spring Boot

Todas as aplicações estão separada, ou seja, cada aplicação tem uma JVM dedicada. Para o controle de log, cada aplicação implementa o seu Log4J, sendo utilizado o log4j.properties file (cada aplicação tem o seu file) para configurar e controlar o nível de log.

## Problema

Na aplicação 1 (App JETTY) preciso criar dois menus com as opções:

1. Active Log Debug
2. Active Log Error

Quando o usuário admin em runtime seleciona a opção `Active Log Debug`, as 4 aplicações em execução no servidor devem começar a gerar log nível `Debug`. O mesmo ocorre no caso da opção Active Log Error, todas as 4 aplicações devem começar a gerar log nível `Error`.

Pensei nas seguintes alternativas:

1) Ler o arquivo `.properties` das aplicações (diretório de instalação) e alterar o nível de LOG conforme, substituir a propriedade de `propertyConfigurator.configure()` para `PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch` (RUNTIME)

2) Submeter o comando `-Dorg.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level=TRACE` para cada JVM (RUNTIME)

Não sei se essa forma de pensar esta coerente e se irá funcionar.

Alguém tem alguma ideia ou já vivenciou algum problema parecido, vários Log4J em JVMs múltiplas?

Answer (score 1):

## Sobre as soluções apresentadas na pergunta

> 1) Ler o arquivo .properties das aplicações...

Configurar o Log4J para monitorar o arquivo de configuração funcionaria e seria uma boa solução, prevista na arquitetura da biblioteca.

Somente verifique se você está usando a última versão da biblioteca. Na versão `1.2`, a funcionalidade *watchdog* é [desencorajada](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a3.6) para aplicações JEE pois a nova thread usava para monitorar o arquivo não é destruída se a aplicação for atualizada sem reiniciar o servidor.

> 2) Submeter o comando...

Submeter um parâmetro de linha de comando para uma JVM ativa é impossível.

## Alternativas possíveis

### Monitorar Configuração

Funciona bem se a estrutura de deploy é previsível e as aplicações tem acesso a um diretório em que se pode escrever no servidor. Pode gerar um pouco de confusão caso o diretório de configuração não seja igual em todos os ambientes.

A [documentação do Log4J 2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) diz como você pode configurar o monitoramento do arquivo. Exemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="5">
...
</Configuration>
```

Aqui o arquivo é verificado a cada 5 segundos - o mínimo permitido na configuração. Isso significa que após a alteração de nível de log, pode demorar até 5 segundos para a nova configuração ter efeito.

### JMX

Usar um [cliente JMX](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/jmx.html) para alterar os logs em tempo de execução.

A vantagem é que não é necessário que a aplicação leia nenhum dado externo e também não é necessária nenhuma implementação adicional nos loggers, embora a aplicação que execute a mudança no nível de log precisa quais as aplicações estão operando para se comunicar com elas.

### Appender remoto

Ainda outra alternative é criar um serviço separado para os logs usando, por exemplo, o [SocketAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SocketAppender).

Nesse caso, as duas aplicações se conectam a uma terceira que cuida exclusivamente dos logs.

A vantagem de logs "remotos" é que você pode escalar o ambiente e ainda manter os logs centralizados.

A atualização do nível de log pode ser feita de qualquer forma já mencionada acima.

### Appender assíncrono

Usar um appender assíncrono pode diminuir o impacto da geração de logs no desempenho, principalmente se o modo `DEBUG` estiver ativo.

Comment: utluiz muito obrigado pela ajuda foi extremamente esclarecedor.